# How do I specify adding files in git and "override" CR/LF translation for the repository for just the added files

Tags: git

Of course first can it be done.
The desire to specify a set of files or a whole folder to be untranslated no matter what platform the local copy is on.

This is for a script that builds docker image files.  The docker build copies files from the build platform (windows OR linux) to the docker virtual image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`.gitattributes` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#gitattributes-Settostringvalueauto) for specifying an eol directive for a specific set of files:

```
local/path/* eol=crlf
```

That works if you know exactly what set of files you need to force to crlf.

Comment: after testing found I needed to do do:
"unixFiles/**/* -text"

an annoying side effect is it effects diffing but it prevents ANY translation of any files in the folder no matter what the platform.